# Javascript replace() and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to use javascript and regex to replace a substring in a url.

```
myurl.com/?page_id=2&paged=2
```

shall become

```
myurl.com/?page_id=2&paged=3
```

this is my code that doesnt seem to work:

```
nextLink = 'myurl.com/?page_id=2&paged=2'
nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/paged\=\/[0-9]?/, 'paged='+ pageNum);
```

What am i doing wrong here? Im new to regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it to match `/paged`, but there's no `/paged` in your string. Also, `[0-9]?` probably isn't what you want for the digits. Try this:

```
nextLink.replace(/\&paged=[0-9]+/, 'paged=' + pageNum);
```

That tells it to replace `&pageid=...` (where `...` is a series of one or more digits) with the given string.

Comment: +1, I would add a note about what kind of chars needs to be escaped.

Comment: Both answers works like a charm, just missed out on the '&' in the second argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the `=`, and you have some additional slashes to match that don't exist in your sample url. Without them, it should work:

```
nextLink = nextLink.replace(/[?&]paged=[0-9]?/, 'paged='+ pageNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours:

```
nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/paged\=\/[0-9]?/, 'paged='+ pageNum);
```

Mine:

```
nextLink = nextLink.replace(/&paged=[0-9]?/, 'paged='+ pageNum);
```

i.e. you wrote `\/` when you meant `&`. You also wrote it before the digits for some reason. And you don't need to escape `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Why use regular expressions, when you can use the [excellent `URI.js` library](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/)?

```
URI("myurl.com/?page_id=2&paged=2")
    .removeQuery("paged")  // remove so we don't have a duplicate
    .addQuery("paged", pageNum)
    .toString();
```

You don't need to worry about escaping, `URI.js` does everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use callback function:

```
var r = new RegExp("paged=(\\d+)");
s = s.replace(r, function($1, $2){ return "paged=" + (parseInt($2, 10) + 1); });
```

See **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QUxsj/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Too many slashes. `\/` will try to match a literal slash which is not there:

```
nextLink = nextLink.replace(/paged=[0-9]?/, 'paged='+ pageNum);
```

However, I think there should be better methods to parse and re-assemble URLs in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using regex.

```
var url ="myurl.com/?page_id=2&paged=2" , pageNum=3;
url = url.split("paged=")[0]+"paged="+pageNum;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s4tmR/)