# javascript replace query string value

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [add or update query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter)

I am trying to replace the page number in the query string no matter what digit is to 1.

query string

```
index.php?list&page=2&sort=epub
```

javascript

```
window.location.href.replace(new RegExp("/page=.*?&/"), "page=1&")
```

Comment: What was the question again?

Comment: This question looks very familiar.

Comment: I was thinking of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211588/javascript-replace-and-regex.

Answer (score 11):

Your code looks *almost* right; however:

- you need to use *either* `new RegExp` *or* the special `//` regex syntax, but not both.
- the `replace` method doesn't modify the string in-place, it merely returns a modified copy.
- rather than `.*?`, I think it makes more sense to write `\d+`; more-precise regexes are generally less likely to go awry in cases you haven't thought of.

So, putting it together:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/page=\d+/, "page=1");
```